# Update SQL From DataGridView

Tags: sql, vb.net, sql-server-2008, visual-studio-2008, datagridview

I am populating a DataGridView from a SQL Server 2008 database table.
I then allow users to edit the values in the DataGridView, what I am struggling on is how to then write these changes back to the SQL table on a button press?

I am populating using this:

```
 Try

            Dim command As New SqlCommand
            Dim adapter As New SqlDataAdapter

            DutyRef = DutyRef.Trim
            Dim DutyDetails As String = "SELECT * from MyTable WHERE Col1 = 1"


            If ds1.Tables("DT_Test").Rows.Count > 0 Then
                ds1.Tables("DT_Test").Rows.Clear()
                Tab2_DGVDuty.Refresh()
            End If

            SQLConn = New SqlConnection(SQLConnString)

            command = New SqlCommand(DutyDetails, SQLConn)
            adapter.SelectCommand = command
            adapter.Fill(ds1, "DT_Test")

            Tab2_DGVDuty.DataSource = ds1.Tables("DT_Test")
            Tab2_DGVDuty.Columns("ID").Visible = False


            adapter.Dispose()
            command.Dispose()
            SQLConn.Close()

        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [`SqlDataAdapter.Update`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldataadapter.update.aspx)

This article may help you: [How To Update a SQL Server Database by Using the SqlDataAdapter Object in Visual Basic .NET](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308055)